# MySQL -> How do I combine two databases in one view

Tags: mysql, view

I have two databases with exactly the same structure. I need to create one view of the combined data. This is my view on one database (name it D1):

```
select 
`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` 
from (`wp_postmeta` join `wp_posts` on((`wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `wp_posts`.`ID`))) 
where (`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound')
```

Database 2 (name it D2) is exactly identical, I just need to merge the data in one view of both databases on the same named tables. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Add columns you want in the following query and try this :**

```
create view ViewName as select * from Database1.Tablename.columnname,Database2.Tablename.columname;
```

Comment: I understand the first part, and altered it. But now I know for sure my join is not correct, how do I deal with that?

Comment: select 
`D1.wp_posts.ID`,`D2.wp_posts.ID` AS `ID`,
`D1.wp_posts.post_date`,`D2.wp_posts.post_date` AS `post_date`,
`D1.wp_postmeta.meta_key`,`D2.wp_postmeta.meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
`D1.wp_postmeta.meta_value`, `D2.wp_postmeta.meta_value` AS `meta_value` 

from (`D1.wp_postmeta`,`D2.wp_postmeta` join `D1.wp_posts`,`D2.wp_posts` 
on ((`D1.wp_postmeta.post_id`,`D2.wp_postmeta.post_id` = `D1.wp_posts.ID`,`D2.wp_posts.ID`))) 
where (`D1.wp_posts.post_type`,`D2.wp_posts.post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound')

Comment: what output you are getting ? how do you want the output to be ? Also try with Combining the databases with minimum columns first inorder to avoid confusion.If the query goes fine then add more columns and check.

Comment: I am trying to get a view that combines the data of two databases with identical tables. So I can use that view to process the data. In my question above is the query, in working order. I just need to pull data from another database & table into this view

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UNION` clause. See [UNION Syntax from Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, perhaps this works, but I keep on getting an error:

Comment: select 
`D1`.`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`,
`D1`.`wp_posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
`D1`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
`D1`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` 

from (`D1`.`wp_postmeta` join `D1`.`wp_posts` on((`D1`.`wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `D1`.`wp_posts`.`ID`))) 
where (`D1`.`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound')

UNION

Comment: select 
`D2`.`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`,
`D2`.`wp_posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
`D2`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
`D2`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value` 

from (`D2`.`wp_postmeta` join `D2`.`wp_posts` on((`D2`.`wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `D2`.`wp_posts`.`ID`))) 
where (`D2`.`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound')

Comment: I am getting an collation error, I've checked all the tables and even the database, they are all on utf8mb4_unicode_ci (I've changed them, as they where not equal) but same error.

Comment: @MaltaCode could you please update your question with UNION and the specific error you are getting? Tks!